# .htaccess - Deny from all except index.php and current directory ./

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## .htaccess

### 'Deny from all' all files except index.php and current directory ./

Hi all, I'm trying for too much time a stupid thing that had to work but i don't know how to do it.

**In this way i can give 403 error to users for all files except index.php page (images and CSS also)**

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

**But I want to add also the current directory [./] to allowed search**

How to do it? Plz

Because if I search THIS URL from my browser --> https://hostname.com/403dir/ it gives me 403 error and I don't want it.

**TNKS**

Comment: TNKS 2 RavinderSingh13 but this solution... it's good, but I want to make a file to put in the folder that had to do this work so in this way I can reuse it. Just CTRL+C and CTRL+V. It's good with *RewriteEngine ON* and *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}* by using *RewriteRule*. But I'm not a man that looks beside or upside the root. A definitive solution PLS. Thank u tha same

Comment: Hello, this solution will help you if you try it once, that comment to check your root is to make sure we are on same page. Kindly try my solution once and you could let me know under my answer's comment section how it goes, thank you.

Comment: I respond you over mine. I tryed. It works goodly. I don't comment so much, just what needed. It's good...I sayd. Thank u to respond my answer – RavinderSingh13

Comment: Wanna wait before to vote (like election). I can't see so much time the same things. Everyone talks about how to answer on SO and not thinks to respond correctly @RavinderSingh13 tnk u da same. By

Comment: Sure, cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: :>)  @RavinderSingh13 by

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Make sure your htaccess file is in your root path(besides 403dir path NOT inside 403dir).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/403dir/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

---

---

OR use a single condition itself as follows, make sure either you use above solution OR following solution only at a time please.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/403dir|index\.php$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Good Answer...!